# Celery how to pass arguments to linked task (which is bound)?

Tags: python, celery, task

I have 2 tasks, which one after success should start second and pass results. Both task are
`bind=True` because of logic of reporting retries.

I call this task by:

```py
async def foobar(x: int):
    task = foo.apply_async(kwargs={'x': x}, link=bar.si())
```

But have no idea how to pass result to bar task. [Docs](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/calling.html) show only example without bind, and in my case result is not passed to second task `bar`

Traceback show that y is not passed:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 503, in trace_task
    signature(callbacks[0], app=app).apply_async(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/canvas.py", line 219, in apply_async
    return _apply(args, kwargs, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 537, in apply_async
    check_arguments(*(args or ()), **(kwargs or {}))
TypeError: bar() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'
```

```
@celery_app.task(name="foo", bind=True,
                 autoretry_for=(Exception,),
                 default_retry_delay=1,
                 retry_backoff=2,  # <- wait 1s before the 1st retry
                 max_retries=2,
                 retry_jitter=False)
def foo(self, x: int, *args):
    logger.info(f'{self.request.id}, countdown: {self.request.retries}, max_retries: {self.max_retries}')
    return {"x": x}


@celery_app.task(name="bar", bind=True,
                 autoretry_for=(Exception,),
                 default_retry_delay=1,
                 retry_backoff=2,  # <- wait 1s before the 1st retry
                 max_retries=2,
                 retry_jitter=False)
def bar(self, y: int):
    logger.info(f'{self.request.id}, countdown: {self.request.retries}, max_retries: {self.max_retries}')
    return {"y_which_should_be_x": y}
```

Comment: All you need to do is to use the [Chain](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/canvas.html#chains) primitive. Once chained together, your newly created workflow will work as you intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that I can just use:

`task = (foo.s(x) | bar.s()).apply_async()` and it's working as intended.

Comment: Yes, Celery uses pipe operator to for an easy way to build [Chains](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/canvas.html#chains).